# Can't import telebot from pyTelegramAPI

Tags: python

i have problem with import telebot in pyTelegramAPI.
My error is this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yaser/Desktop/pyhton codes/Insta-tel-bot/insta/telegram.py", line 2, in 
import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

I have python 3.9.7 and Pip 21.

- I don't install telebot.
  can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

or go to [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/). Try to do some research next time before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

What platform do you use for pyhton?
If you use pyhcharm you can install modules in packages side.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31293964)

Answer (score 0):

User virtualenv [SOME ARTICLE](https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv):
windows: `pip install virtualenv`
Linux: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv`

Activation:
windows: `<env_name>/Scripts/activate`
Linux: `source env\bin\activate`

Then:
`pip install -r requirements.txt` or just `pytelegrambotapi` then `pip install pytelegrambotapi`